# Codeigniter[Angelleye library]: "Receiver PayPal accounts must be unique" error

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have used angelleye/paypal-codeigniter API for implementing the Paypal Adaptive Payment in my Codeigniter Project.
I have the similar setup like that of https://ci.angelleye.com/paypal/samples/demo/ ON MY LOCALHOST

I have developer paypal account which has 2 merchant sandbox account and one sender sandbox account.While payment I am transferring the funds from  sender to 2 receivers.

On my localhost I clicked on the link of Adaptive Payment from the three libraries(Payments Pro , Adaptive Payments,PayFlow) mentioned on that page. Everything was working fine till some time back.

But unfortunately now on click of  Adaptive Payment link I am getting following errors in $PayPalRequestData as RESPONSE:

```
 Array
(
['Errors'] => array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Receiver] => 
        [Category] => Application
        [Domain] => PLATFORM
        [ErrorID] => 579040
        [ExceptionID] => 
        [Message] => Receiver PayPal accounts must be unique.
        [Parameter] => receiver
        [Severity] => Error
        [Subdomain] => Application
)
  [Ack] => Failure
[Build] => 20420247
[CorrelationID] => 581ecdae58e50
[Timestamp] => 2016-03-04T01:41:05.725-08:00
[PayKey] =>
[PaymentExecStatus] =>
[RedirectURL] =>
[XMLRequest] => <displayed request string>
[XMLResponse] => <displayed response string>
    )

 Array
(
['Errors'] => array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Receiver] => 
        [Category] => Application
        [Domain] => PLATFORM
        [ErrorID] => 579017
        [ExceptionID] => 
        [Message] =>The amount for the primary receiver must be greater than
            or equal to the total of other chained receiver amounts
        [Parameter] => receiver
        [Severity] => Error
        [Subdomain] => Application
)
[Ack] => Failure
[Build] => 20420247
[CorrelationID] => d85cb50b00e2e
[Timestamp] => 2016-03-04T01:46:01.853-08:00
[PayKey] => 
[PaymentExecStatus] => 
[RedirectURL] => 
  [XMLRequest] => <displayed request string>
[XMLResponse] => <displayed response string>

    )
```

The REQUEST I sent is

```
$Receiver = array(
'Amount' = '12.00', 
'Email' = 'receiver_1@domain.com', 
'InvoiceID' = '123-ABCDEFG', 
'PaymentType' = 'SERVICE', 
'PaymentSubType' = '', 
'Phone' = array('CountryCode' = '', 'PhoneNumber' = '',
'Extension' = ''),
'Primary' = 'true' 
);

$Receiver = array(
'Amount' = '5.00', 
'Email' = 'receiver_2@domain.com', 
'InvoiceID' = '123-ABCDEFG', 
'PaymentType' = 'SERVICE', 
'PaymentSubType' = '', 
'Phone' = array('CountryCode' = '', 'PhoneNumber' = '',
'Extension' = ''),
'Primary' = 'true' 
);
```

Can someone please tell me what there errors are? and how to solve those errors.

Comment: Andrew Angell answred:
$XMLRequest had the 2 same email_ids due to which this errorid 579040 has occured, errorid 579017 comes when chained payment rule is voilated.
Thanks Angelleye

Comment: Also, there can only be one Primary Receiver, and I can see you are sending Primary=true for both.

Comment: I worked this out with @Vinay via my support emails.  Turns out he was accidentally sending the same email account for 2 different receivers in his request.